# How to create customised nsdictionary from two nsarrays

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have two arrays like this

```
idArray:(
    "548c2afe-5943-4929-9c6b-b544f5022115-sff45v-kjsa68f",
    "656e8481-f2d5-4843-bebd-883f1b0f79d0-ksfns-gg456gg"
)

namesArray:(
"king",
"queen"
)
```

I want to make a dictionary which looks like this

```
[{
"id" : "548c2afe-5943-4929-9c6b-b544f5022115-sff45v-kjsa68f",
"name" : "king"
},
{
"id" : "3656e8481-f2d5-4843-bebd-883f1b0f79d0-ksfns-gg456gg",
"name" : "queen"
}]
```

Help me in this issue. i have tried this

```
NSDictionary *fullDictionary = @{@"id": userarray, @"scandat": scandatesarray};

                                NSError *error;
                                NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:fullDictionary options:0 error:&error];
                                NSLog(@"%@", fullDictionary);
```

and the output is

```
{
    id =     (
        "656e8481-f2d5-4843-bebd-883f1b0f79d0",
        "548c2afe-5943-4929-9c6b-b544f5022115"
    );
    scandat =     (
        "2016-05-28 16:50:30",
        "2016-05-28 16:50:59"
    );
}
```

Comment: what you have tried ... can you post some code

Comment: Bhavin.. can you pls check now

Comment: yes same number of values

Comment: Varun I gave you my answer from my mobile phone.First I gave you solution from your question what you asked first.Once you edit your question after that I edited my answer from my mobile phone.

Comment: Varun try my answer.It is useful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not making a dictionary - your target object is an `NSArray` containing `NSDictionary` objects as its elements.

```
NSMutableArray *res = [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray *keys = @[@"id", @"name"];
for (int i = 0 ; i != idArray.count ; i++) {
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary
        dictionaryWithObjects: @[idArray[i], nameArray[i]]
        forKeys: keys
    ];
    [res addObject:dict];
}
```

Comment: yeah :D just did that

Comment: hey i know this is silly but i am not getting that  quotes for id and name.. i tried with @"\"id\"" but no use..can you help me in this?? i want "id" and "name"

Comment: @varun This is formatting. Print JSON string, quotes should be there.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray  *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for(int i=0;i<idArray.count;i++)
{

   NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"id",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[idArray objectAtIndex:i]],@"name",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[namesArray objectAtIndex:i]]];


   [arr addObject:dic];

  }
```

Comment: hey i know this is silly but i am not getting that quotes for id and name.. i tried with @"\"id\"" but no use..can you help me in this?? i want "id" and "name"

Comment: Put @"id"  and @"name"  please remove slash

Comment: You can't get the quotes no matter what you try to get the double quotes,you can't get or set.

Answer (score 0):

You want an array containing dictionaries.

So you create a mutable array, then you create lots of dictionaries, each with two key/value pairs, and add them to the mutable array.

I hope having to write actual code doesn't frighten you.

On the other